# Loop in django app - check if object already created

Tags: python, django

i have problem with django app:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    requirements = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name='wym', symmetrical=False)
    status = ''

class EndedModules(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    module = models.ForeignKey('Module')
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and in view:

```
modules = Module.objects.all()
for module in modules:
    try:
        exist = EndedModules.objects.get(user=request.user,module=module)
        if exist.end_time:
            module.status = 'ended'
        else:
            module.status = 'started not ended'
    except:
        module.status = 'not exist'
```

but when i trying to show in templates:

```
{% for module in modules %}
    {% for element in module.requirements.all %}
        {{ element.status }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

its not working.

There is any another way to do this?

i tried to to this in model but i dont have access to request.user

thanks!

Comment: How about showing the error message and stack trace? Where is the code rendering the template? What is `module.wym`?

Comment: Or if there's no stack trace, then use {{ element }} instead of {{ element.status }} and post it in your question

Comment: Nothing displays on {{ element.status }} but on main module object module.status is working fine

Comment: Why do you have end_time.end_time, shouldn't it be exist.end_time ?

Comment: from the code you have shown us, you are not populating the model `Module` at all.

Comment: @BrentWashburne how to show stack trace? when i used {{element}} i got only 'Modul object'

Comment: There is no stack trace because your code is not throwing an exception, which is good.  The reason you don't see any status messages is because you don't save them back to the database.  Add the line "module.save()" at the end of the loop in your view (indented the same level as the "try:" and "except:" lines).

Comment: How is the view connected to the template?

Comment: @BrentWashburne, his "status" is not a model field so that won't do anything. He appears to be trying to set python attributes for use in the template (perfectly valid) - just getting confused in his template logic.

Comment: how do you render your template?

Comment: @BrentWashburne Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita explained it correctly but still i dont know solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `status` attribute on the first `module` loop, while iterating over a completely different set of data in your template (`requirements.all`).

Assuming you're passing `modules` to the template context, according to your view, you've set attributes on the outer `module` loop but not the inner `element` loop. The outer loop corresponds to `{{ module.status }}` in your template.

`{{ element.status }}` is iterating over a newly created queryset and will reflect what you have in your class definition which is `status = ''`

```
{% for module in modules %}
    {% for element in module.requirements.all %}
        {{ element.status }}
        <!-- ^^^ this doesn't have a status value - only {{ module.status }} -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I guessed that but wrote this question here to get some solutions. Do you know how to do it and dont check again every requirment again?

Comment: @user2225970, you're going to have to clarify your question. You've provided apps, views, template, and 2 sentences: "I have a problem..."  and "it's not working". I've described why it's clear `{{ element.status }}` wouldn't render anything.

Comment: Okey, you are right. I have modules model and every module could have requirments (manytomany field self). For example Module 3 needs module 1 and 2 to be started. So in my template i have list of modules and requirments of every module, for example: http://pastebin.com/phSdSwCG . In EndedModules model i have records if user already done module. example: user 1 done module 1. To sum up, i checking every module if done but i dont want to check it again in requirments of every module (if its already done - becasue requirments are main modules too). Sory if not clear, eng. my 2nd language

Comment: I tried to do it in function in model but i dont know to get acccess to request.user in models.